# Thymeleaf add multiple parameters to URL in one go

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, url-parameters

Given I have MVC endpoint with mapping:

```
@RequestMapping
public String eventHistory(final Model model,
                           @PageableDefault(sort = {"id"}, direction = DESC) final Pageable pageable,
                           final EventHistoryFilter eventHistoryFilter) {
    ...

    model.addAttribute("eventHistoryFilter", eventHistoryFilter);
}
```

where `EventHistoryFilter` is:

```
final class EventHistoryFilter {
    private Long eventId;
    private String eventType;
    private String eventDateFrom;
    private String eventDateTo;

    ...
}
```

and in thymeleaf template I would like to construct URL with parameters, e.g.:

```
th:href="@{/event-history(page=${page.number-1},eventId=${eventHistoryFilter.eventId},eventType=${eventHistoryFilter.eventType},eventDateFrom=${eventHistoryFilter.eventDateFrom},eventDateTo=${eventHistoryFilter.eventDateTo})}"
```

How can I add multiple parameters into URL in one go?

I didn't find it here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#adding-parameters

I'd like to avoid specifying each parameter one by one.

EDIT:
I tried to use https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#building-uris-to-controllers

```
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName("EHE#eventHistory").arg(2, eventHistoryFilter).build();
```

but resolved URL doesn't contain any request parameters.

and thymeleaf counterpart:

```
th:href="${#mvc.url('EHE#eventHistory').arg(2,__${eventHistoryFilter}__).build()}"
```

fails during evaluation.

Comment: where are you facing issue? Where do you want multiple parameters? in URL or in a controller?

Comment: I want to create URL using th:href with multiple parameters in thymeleaf template html file based on information provided by EventHistoryFilter object (which is added into model inside controller mapping)

Comment: Then url mentioned in your question is correct.

Comment: The problem with that is currently I have around 11 parameters and th:href value is very long (I added only 4 to keep question short). 
Is there a way to add these parameters in one go? I tried to introduce some method on EventHistoryFilter and call it from html file, but it wasn't working

Comment: The answer is no -- there is no shortcut for building a url using Thymeleaf's standard url syntax.  You definitely can call other methods to simplify your html,  but you don't really have enough information here.  Why do you say `I tried to introduce some method on EventHistoryFilter and call it from html file, but it wasn't working` -- this definitely works if your syntax is correct.

Comment: I thought I would create a method on EventHistoryFilter which would return string containing key=value request param pairs.
But then I thought it's not compatible with Thymeleaf way of adding parameters.
Am I correct?

Have you seen my EDIT part? What do you think?